# "Ce à quoi" vs "à quoi"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-interrogatifs

I've been going through examples in a French grammar workbook, and I saw this example sentence:

> J'ignore ce à quoi il s'abonne.

But then I also saw this:

> Je ne sais pas à quoi il pense.

These seem to be identical use cases to me. Why does one use *ce à quoi* and the other only *à quoi* ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In object position “*ce à quoi …*” stands for a direct object (in the main clause) described by means of a relative subordination clause (in which it is an indirect object). Compare (grammatically):

> J'ignore ce à quoi il s'abonne.
>   J'ignore ses raisons.
>   J'ignore ce qui t'amuse.
>   J'ignore ce dont il parle.
>   J'ignore ce que tu fais.

A direct “*à quoi…*” is used when the verb is followed by an [indirect interogative clause](http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_2_06_La_proposition_interrogative_indirecte.shtml). Compare:

> Je ne sais pas à quoi il pense.
>   Je ne sais pas combien il y a de jours dans l'année.
>   J'ignore à quoi il s'abonne.
>   J'ignore quel age il a.

What follows the verb can be used as a standalone question:

> À quoi pense-t-il ?
>   Combien y a-t-il de jours dans l'année ?
>   À quoi s'abonne-t-il ?
>   Quel age a-t-il ?

---

Note: *Savoir* followed by an object which is not an indirect interrogative or an infinitive clause is rare in modern French (example: *Je ne sais pas la Physique.*). Therefore, I would avoid writing “*je ne sais pas ce à quoi*”. But notice that

> Je ne sais pas ce que tu lis.
>   Je ne sais pas ce qui le dérange.

are perfectly fine, *ce que* and *ce qui* can as well introduce an indirect interrogative clause in which the *direct object*, respectively the *subject*, is unknown (and isn't a person). The associated questions are:

> *Qu'est-ce que* tu lis ? (or… *Que* lis-tu ?)
>   *Qu'est-ce qui* le dérange ? (no alternative, *qui* is only used for persons)

Yes French is weird sometimes.

Comment: Oh my god this is really hard for me to follow grammatically. Too early in the morning right now.

Comment: I've added some more. Might or might not make it easier to digest…

Comment: "Je ne sais pas combien il y a de jours dans l'année." is that really how you say that? Not "...combien de jours il y a dans l'année" ?

Comment: I also cannot ascertain ANY difference between "J'ignore à quoi il s'abonne." and "J'ignore ce à quoi il s'abonne," two of your examples where one apparently has a relative subordination clause and the other has an indirect interrogative clause.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Both are possible and mean the same thing (this is an answer to both comments).

Comment: These examples seem to support the idea that you put *ce* when not intending to introduce an indirect interrogative. *Il défend ce en quoi il croit.* *C'est ce à quoi elle rêve.* In these, meaning indicates that the reference of the relative clause is fixed (rather than in question).

Answer (score 3):

> - J'ignore *ce à quoi* il s'abonne.
> - Je ne sais pas *à quoi* il pense.

Le *ce* ajoute de la précision, à l'objet *quoi*, et cela induit un contexte.

On peut reformuler la première phrase en remplaçant le *ce*:

> - J'ignore *précisément à quoi* il s'abonne (sous-entendu : mais je sais qu'il s'abonne à quelque chose).

et contextualiser la seconde :

> - Je ne sais pas *à quoi* il pense, et je n'en ai aucune idée.
> - Je ne sais pas *ce à quoi* il pense, mais je devine que cela doit être pénible.

---

**Complément :** Le [site d'exercice](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/pronoms_relatifs.htm#.UjKwhH_kuSo) donne l'utilisation pratique des pronoms relatifs dont  *ce à quoi*.

Comment: Not sure en French answer is adequate when the person asking doesn't show any sign of being proficient enough in French to understand your answer.

Comment: @Aki I can only read english, I speak it like a chinese panda, and do so many errors ... so a beginner can takes habit to read french, even if he is at my english level, it is also for others francophone learners ; and I've had sample link.

Comment: Ha I can always read cl-r's answers. Mon abilité de lire en français est très bien developpé; c'est mon abilité de comprendre le français à l'orale qui est terriblement faible. Malgré ça, il y a parfois des choses qui je ne comprends pas, et puis je crée une question ici comme celui-ci!

Comment: @Aerovistae -- Commentaire sympathique, mais... *abilité*...  hum.... *habileté* pourrait être plus glamour, mais on emploie plutôt *agilité* pour dire que l'on excelle, ou *ma capacité* à lire le français. Reconstruire la phrase plus simplement : "Je lis [ facilement | sans (aucune) difficulté ] le français".

Answer (score 1):

It only looks like a difference of verbosity to me, possibly coming from a matter of taste, but I have no reference to support this.

The following usage sounds fine with me (also the second one sounds heavy):

> J'ignore à quoi il pense.
>
> Je ne sais pas ce à quoi il pense.

Interestingly, in this different example, one cannot use *"ce"* anymore:

> J'ignore à quelle heure il part.
>
> Je ne sais pas à quelle heure il part.

Comment: *Je ne sais pas ce à quoi il pense* sounds a bit odd to me. We rarely use *savoir quelque chose* where *quelque chose* stands for something (like *ses pensées*). It's too old fashioned, and doesn't even fit in this context.

Comment: I agree it sounds heavy, but I think it is still valid: *"Je ne m'intéresse qu'à la langue. Tu sais cela."* It's a bit hard to tell as usage in spoken language tends to be flexible (*"Tu sais quoi ?"*).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez what would you say instead?

Comment: @Aerovistae: “Je ne sais pas à quoi il pense.”