# Comment traduire « what I'm thinking about » en français ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

On peut transformer « on mange des choses » en « ce qu'on mange » , et « j'ai besoin des choses » en « ce dont j'ai besoin » . Mais je ne sais pas transformer « Je pense aux choses » de la même manière.

Comment: Les choses auxquelles je pense ?

Comment: @Random Ça marche, je crois, mais je veux bien savoir s'il existe une phrase avec « ce » ou bien « cela » , par exemple « à cela que je pense »  , peut-être.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Je vois 2 formulations possibles :

> Les choses **auxquelles** je pense

ou

> Ce **à quoi** je pense

**Complément :**

Comme le souligne Papa Poule, dans une phrase, on peut aussi omettre le "ce" :

> On a découvert à quoi il pense
>   Je sais à quoi tu penses

Comment: Est-ce vrai que la deuxième option est correcte ? Peut-on dire, par exemple, _On a découvert ce à quoi il pense._ pour dire "We have found out what he's thinking about." ?

Comment: @AndrewSlattery oui, c'est tout à fait correct. Je trouve personnellement le "**ce à** quoi" peu élégant, mais cl-r pense le contraire, après tout, ce n'est qu'une question d'esthétique :)

Comment: +1, but out of curiosity, would just “A quoi tu/je/il penses” (without the “ce”) be idiomatic enough to work in many contexts to mean “what someone’s thinking about”? (“Je sais à quoi tu penses, cheri”, for example, or would the “ce” be needed even here to be grammatically correct?) Thanks.

Comment: @PapaPoule En effet, c'est un point très intéressant, je l'ajoute à la réponse !

Comment: @PapaPoule In fact, in that last example it sounds wrong to put "ce". I'm not sure I can explain why.

Comment: Pour la dernière remarque: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/ce-%c3%a0-quoi-vs-%c3%a0-quoi