# What does "ce sur quoi" mean?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

I have never seen this one before, someone here wrote the sentence:

> On peut également préciser **ce sur quoi** porte la demande: par exemple, "Pouvez-vous répéter la question?"

What does *ce sur quoi* mean and when and how should it be used?

Comment: (I sort of get it, but not well enough to know when to use it as opposed to *ce que.*)

Comment: *La demande porte sur ____*. Sur quoi porte la demande ? Pourriez-vous preciser ce sur quoi porte la demande ?

Comment: I also had to look up *porter sur*, I didn't know that combination.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is similar to the answer to [ce à quoi vs à quoi](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/ce-%c3%a0-quoi-vs-%c3%a0-quoi).

In French *préciser* can be followed by either an object or an interrogative clause. Examples:

> Préciser sa pensée.
>
> Préciser comment il faut faire.

If you choose to define the thing-to-be-made-precise with a relative clause you can for example use:

> On peut également préciser ce sur quoi porte la demande.
>
> On peut également préciser la personne qui a fait cette demande.

Or, if you choose to use an interrogative clause directly:

> On peut également préciser sur quoi porte la demande.
>
> On peut également préciser qui a fait cette demande.

The first way is in this case slightly more idiomatic, but it's hard to tell why.

Comment: "Préciser comment il faut faire" ? "Specify how he needs to do"?

Comment: And did you mean *ce sur quoi* in the second to last example sentence?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Specify how one should proceed or how it should be done. (*Il* is impersonal here, and there's no equivalent phrasing in English.) But any interrogative clause (a question without subjet–verb inversion) would do. Préciser… “quand il revient”, “où il va”, or “sur quoi porte la demande” or “quelles sont les possibilités”.

Answer (score 2):

It could be use several times in french. It means **c'est sur quoi**. In English, you could translate to :

> On what (thereupon).

Hope it can help you.

Comment: c'est inexact. c'est sur quoi ... est une proposition. alors que le ce sur quoi est un pronom et peut être réutiliser dans une phrase (c'est le cas dans la question: c'est un COD).

Answer (score 1):

In french:

**1 Ce est un pronom = cela** . la suite après *ce* précise ce qu'est cela.

Ce sur quoi porte la question => la question porte sur cela

On peut utiliser la même tournure avec des verbes directs ou indirects:

- ce que je vois  (je vois cela)
- ce à quoi je pense (je pense à cela)
- ce dont je me souviens (je me souviens de cela)

**2 En tant que prénom, il peut être utilisé comme COD, sujet, ...**

On peut préciser ce sur quoi ... => ce ... est un COD

Pensez-vous à ce ... => ce ... est un COI

ce dont je parle est bizarre => ce ... est un sujet