# Is this a correct use of dont, and auquel?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

I wanted to ask if my following answers are correct

> Je sais pas dont je parle

Means "I don't know what I'm talking about" right?
And if you say

> Je sais pas ce que j'en parle

Means "I don't know what I talk of it"

And

> Je sais pas auquel je pense

Means "I don't know what I'm thinking"

And

> Je sais pas ce que j'y pense

Means "I don't know what I think of it"
Right?

Comment: Why is it that you ask questions here about complicated structure but fail to not use the ne...pas in your negative sentences? That is hard to understand. Are  you perhaps trying to sound like what one hears in movies when people talk fast and say; Sais pas etc? Just wondering....

Comment: I wrote this on a paper during school haha, I had to write it quickly

Comment: The examples I mean which I just copied into my phone

Comment: You wrote it on a paper? But then you had to write it again to post it here, right? You mean in a paper, right?

Comment: That's a very confusing sentence um... Yes I wrote the examples on my notebook, then copied them unto my phone on the stack exchange app haha. Why did you have to repeat paper haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Je sais pas dont je parle"* is not possible, because *"dont"* is a relative pronoun referring to a noun that is a complement of the preceding proposition, and here you have omitted it. Moreover, "*pas*" is not really a negation: it has to be used with "*ne*". You should say:

"Je **ne** sais **pas** de quoi je parle"
or
"Je ne connais pas **ce** dont je parle"

Then
*"Je sais pas ce que j'en parle"* is wrong as well

Here, you could say:

"Je **ne** sais **pas** ce que j'en **dis**" (I don't know what I say about it)

This is correct, although the meaning is rather queer. You cannot say *"ce que j'en parle"* because parler is not a transitive verb, meanwhile "dire" is transitive..

Bad luck once more,

*"Je sais pas auquel je pense"*

is wrong also. "*auquel*" like "*dont*" refers to a complement of the preceding proposition, but with the sens of "*to that*" meanwhile "dont" means "*of that*". But in your sentence, you have no referring complement, so you should say:

"Je **ne** sais **pas** **à quoi** je pense".

*"Je sais pas ce que j'y pense"*

is wrong, although the motto of the English kings is *"honi soit qui mal y pense"*, but this is old French from the middle-age. Here, you cannot say "y" be cause "y" means "to that", which has no sense here, where you mean "about that", so you must use "en". The correct form would be:

*"Je **ne** sais **pas** ce que j'**en** pense"*.

Comment: I feel so stupid now... Haha, sorry for bothering you and making you have to write that haha. Hope you didn't hurt your head from facepalming

Comment: While this is natural to us, it can be tricky to foreigners. At some point, native speaker don't even need to remember the rule to know the proper expressions. I might have had a spat with BBBreiz, but I have to concede that his knowledge is quite good.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that *dont* and *auquel* (lequel, etc.) really translate to *which* and not *what* for the most part.

Comment: In your example of "Je ne sais pas de quoi je parle" versus "Je ne sais pas ce dont je parle", what are the rules for eliding "ce"? For example, can you say "Je ne sais pas ce à quoi je pense", or is only "Je ne sais pas à quoi je pense" correct?

Comment: "je ne sais pas à quoi je pense" is a correct form. "je ne sais pas ce à quoi je pense" is wrong, but "je ne connais pas ce à quoi je pense" is correct and "je ne connais pas à quoi je pense" would be wrong. Nevertheless, the reason why it is so, is quite hard to explain. If you insist, I will try to, otherwise you may simply trust me...

Comment: There's a very nice discussion here: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/ce-%C3%A0-quoi-vs-%C3%A0-quoi