# Using "ce à qui"?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

"I forgot who she wants to talk to."

> J'ai oublié ____ elle veut parler.

What should go into the blank? *Ce qui*, *ce que*, *qui*, and *que* are out, because *parler* requires the preposition *à* in this context. *Ce à quoi* doesn't work either because we have a person here.

The sensible choice seems to be *ce à qui*, but is this actually used? Otherwise, can we use *à qui*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> J'ai oublié à qui elle veut parler.

As you said, in this context (complément du verbe), you use "qui" when the pronoun replaces someone (usually a person) and you need "à" because in French it is "parler **à** quelqu'un". So the rule is "préposition + qui" for a person ([...]**avec qui** tu manges, [...]**de qui** tu parles, [...]**pour qui** tu travailles, [...]**chez qui** tu vas...).

Note that the "ce à quoi" and "à quoi" are both possible in this context , but "ce à qui" is wrong.

> Je me demande (ce) à quoi tu penses.  (what)

**ce** is however necessary for a direct complement (See [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/ce-%C3%A0-quoi-vs-%C3%A0-quoi) for more details)

> Je fais ce que je dois.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step :

- I forgot = J'ai oublié
- who = qui*
- she wants to talk = elle veut parler
- to = à*

You need to fill the blank in your translation with the (*) missing part.

> > I forgot who she wants to talk to.
>
> J'ai oublié ____ elle veut parler.

→ **J'ai oublié à qui elle veut parler.**