# Relative pronoun in "Ce n'est pas ____ elle veut parler"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

"This is not who she wants to talk to"

> Ce n'est pas ____ elle veut parler.

In a related [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22759/using-ce-%C3%A0-qui), it was pointed out that we can say

> J'ai oublié **à qui** elle veut parler.

In the case with the verb *être*, however, I don't think this would work. Do we have to use *ce à qui*?

Comment: Could you make explicit what you think could be correct solutions, i.e. the options you would consider ? I think that would help you learn/improve, and it also would make the question a bit easier to understand and answer.

Comment: I was thinking *ce à qui* could be a correct solution.

Comment: I you mean "**Ce n'est pas ce à qui elle veut parler.*", then you were almost there ; only *ce* is for objects, and for people we use *celui* or *celle* depending on gender :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways. Indeed, one uses *celui/celle à qui*, like you mention :

> Ce n'est pas - **la personne à qui** - elle veut parler.
>   This is not - the person to whom - she wants to talk to.

and :

> Ce n'est pas - **à lui/elle** - **qu**'elle - veut parler.
>   It is not - to this person - that she - wants to talk to.

Both mean approximately the same, with slight nuances.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would say the following even though it is not a very nice way to say it.

> Ce n'est pas **à elle qu'** elle veut parler.

Which litterally means

> It is not **to her** she wants to talk to.