# « J’ignore ce à quoi il pense. » ou »J’ignore à quoi il pense. »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> J’ignore ce à quoi il pense.

> J’ignore à quoi il pense.

> Je ne sais pas à quoi il pense.

> Je ne sais pas ce à quoi il pense.

Doit-on employer « ce » dans les phrases ci-haut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Ce à quoi" vs "à quoi"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/ce-%c3%a0-quoi-vs-%c3%a0-quoi)

Comment: Not Crystal clear.

Comment: Il n'y a pas consensus dans la page que j'ai proposée. Voilà mon avis: 1:passable, 2:mieux, 3:bien, 4:bof

Comment: J'ignore ses pensées / intentions.  :) Il me semble aussi que la 3ème phrase est la meilleure.

Comment: J’ignore: tournure positive/ je ne sais pas: tournure négative. Les deux ont le même sens.

Comment: Oui, mais certaines tournures sont plus idiomatiques que d'autres. C'est pourquoi je trouve que la 3ème phrase est meilleure.

Comment: D’accord, je comprends ton point de vue!

Comment: Je suis allée voir le lien que jlliagre avait écrit plus haut. Je pense que la réponse de Stéphane Gimenez est la meilleure. // Si tu n'écris pas @ + mon nom dans les commentaires, je ne peux pas savoir si tu m'a dit qqch ou non, je dois revenir sur la page.

Comment: @Oreste C’est bon à savoir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour,

Vos 4 phrases sont correctes.
Néanmoins, certaines passent moins bien que d’autres à l’oral ou à l’écrit.
La meilleure est certainement la n°= 3 ou n°= 1, les autres ne sont honnêtement pas terribles.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French language SE.  Le *pourquoi* est important dans une réponse. Voici le [tour] et le [help].